# Insert data from a server to another server No linked sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to copy data using sqlserver 2008

Server1.database.dbo.table to

Server2.database.dbo.table

Servers are not linked and cannot link them.
Cannot use SSIS or any other BI stuff  I dont know how to use it,not time to learn.

My approach

Scripted all the data "sql server wizard " "Create Data=true"
and then run the script.

my challenge

1. Some columns might not exists in  Server2.database.dbo.table A table
2. some tables might have the same Primary keys and
   foreign keys as destination table so Ignore

what is the best approach?
Any free tools I can use where I can map columns?

At the moment I am going for a manual script where I have generated the Insert and I have manually worked out the dependency order and commented out the columns that have the same primary keys as destination table.

Wondering if there is a better way?

Any suggestions?
Many thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2012/01/31/microsoft-sql-server-migration-assistant-ssma-5-2-is-now-available.aspx
perhaps this can help

Comment: Can you check with the built-in tools available in VS2010(in Data Menu) for schema and data comparison? if that may be of any help to you.

Comment: @Furqan SSDT should be able to do it.

Comment: *Wondering if there is a better way?* SSIS, but you discard it for no good reason. *Cannot use SSIS or any other BI stuff I dont know how to use it,not time to learn.* The import/export data wizard that wraps SSIS in SSMS is incredibly easy to use.

Comment: +1 @ta.speot.is is correct, and if the number of tables you have to copy is more than, say, three, your investment in time in learning SSIS will be dwarfed by the time consumed in scripting and tweaking the scripts for those tables.

Comment: @ta.speot.is I tried to use it and spent 3 hours and then my boss came and said "Have you finished?" I had all sorts of issue that I didnt know how to address is SSIS ,Some dataflow were erroing eg.Columns missing,duplicate key errors,etc.. if you have done it before you probably take mins not hours. I have created a script "manual" that works but not really happy ,was looking for a tool where I could do that "SSIS" is the tool but may be requires knowledge when you start having problems.

Comment: @Furqan I use  the Schema comparison all the time and it does help me but can it write a script to migrate data?How?thanks

Comment: [The import and export wizard is extremely easy to use, if it complains about missing columns pay attention to the column mapping page of the wizard](http://www.jasonyousef.com/2012/05/sql-server-import-and-export-wizard.html). And if you use the Schema Comparison feature of SSDT without issue, [the new release has Data Comparison](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/06/24/announcing-sql-server-data-tools-june-2013.aspx) which is similar, except for data.

Comment: @user231465 , yes the same menu has data comparison option, that also generate relevant scripts, check this option, it might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i ended up writing the scripts as faster than learning ssis as it was a one off.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a controversial suggestion, but consider using MS Access as an intermediary.

Access will let you link both tables, and write a query to copy from one to the other.  It certainly won't be fast, and you may have timeout issues you'll have to address, but you'll get your automatic column-mapping, and if you have MS Office then you'll already have it.

I'm NOT suggesting you download all your data to your PC, but I am suggesting that you try linking both tables into an Access database and copying data from one to the other.

If your target database doesn't have the target tables (though it sounds like it does) you'd have to create them via scripting first, but Access does an adequate job copying data from place to place.  I call it "the poor man's SSIS".

It has the advantage that once you've written the queries you need, and perhaps a macro to execute them in order, you can save them, and re-execute them, or tweak them, without having to manipulate a script.

**SSIS would still be the best solution for your problem**, but if you don't have it available or haven't time to learn to use it, I'd look into Access.